# ListView number decimal keyboard issue

Tags: android, listview, keyboard, android-edittext

I have a listview with EditText. I specified EditText inputType as "numberDecimal". But at first touch on EditText, qwerty keyboard appearing and unable to give input. If i touch again on EditText, decimal keyboard is appearing and i am able to give input. How to get decimal keyboard at first time. I have tried all the possibilities. Please help to resolve the issue.

Here is edittext

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtSize"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/size120"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_2"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_20"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:background="@null"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/edt_input"
    android:drawablePadding="-15dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="0"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:maxLength="6"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_20"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_20"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/gray_dark"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

and this is my listview

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/size5"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:divider="@drawable/sep_ver"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: How are you setting the input type and when are you doing it?